# Which are the polynomials $p$, such that $y^2 = p(x)$ is a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have to find all of the polynomials $p$ with real coefficients, such that the set $M = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : y^2 = p(x)\}$ is a smooth manifold. This is what have I done so far to solve the problem:

The function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $(x,y) \mapsto p(x)-y^2$ is obviously a smooth map of $\mathbb R ^2$ into $\mathbb R$. For an arbitrary $(a,b) \in f^{-1}(0)$, $df_{(a,b)} : T_{(a,b)}\mathbb R ^2 = T_0\mathbb R$ is given by the matrix $(\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} (a) \ \ -2b)$, so $df_{(a,b)}$ is if $b \neq 0$ or $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} (a) \neq 0$. So if for all roots $a \in \mathbb R$ of $p$, $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x} (a) \neq 0$, then $df_x$ will be surjective for all $z \in f^{-1}(0)$ and then using the [Preimage theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem) $M = f^{-1}(0)$ will be a manifold of dimension $1$.

Please tell is my solution correct and are there any other polynomials that satisfies the requirements...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well done! Looks good.

Comment: I agree that this looks right. Observe that the condition is equivalent to the fact that $p$ does not have a multiple real root.

Comment: Thanks, @AndreasCap! Do you know if it can be proven that if $p$ has multiple real roots, then $y^2 = p(x)$ is not a smooth manifold ?

Comment: I think that this can be proved, but I don't know a reference. The basic line of argument should be that this can be reduced to the case that $y^2=x^k$ for some $k\geq 2$. For even $k$, this comes down to $y=\pm x^{k/2}$, which is not a smooth manifold around $x=0$ (since it has two branches).  For $k=3$, you get Neil's parabola, which has a cusp singularity at $x=0$.

Comment: You should be careful about the degenerate case, where $p(x)$ is a constant. In this case $y^2 = c$ are all smooth submanifolds.